# Turtlebot Installation Failure

Tags: ros, turtlebot, rosdeb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all.
when i runing the   "turtlebot_node" faced with this error!!!
'failed to find rosdep daemontools for package turtlebot nod on os:ubuntu version :marverick'

i enter this command 'rosdep install turtlebot_node '
but i saw this error 'rosdep install ERROR: failed to install daemontools .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34173/turtlebot-installation-failure/) by [reza shahabian](https://answers.ros.org/users/2100/reza-shahabian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since it looks like you're using Ubuntu, you should use the debs to install the turtlebot stack. You only need to run rosdep install if you're installing from source. Is there a reason you need to do that?

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-turtlebot
```

should install what you need.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0